# php mysql changing a specifc row

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE a75ting.username
SET points = points - 5
```

i want to change the points column in the database `WHERE username = $usern`

is that how is works?

ALSO-- is the $rows variable a session type of variable? can i only request the db connect once to use $rows anywhere? or do you need to connect to tb per request?

Comment: hi shawn.   assuming you're using mysql      connect (a75ting), sql="update username set points=points-5 where username=$usern" you need to check the structure of the sql statement. you also need to check the returned results to ensure that the query succeeds/fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a table, so the query would be:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET points = points - 5
 WHERE username = 'mike'
```

In php it would be:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Table SET points = points - 5 WHERE username = '". mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'");
```

With regards to your question about session variables, no `$row` would not be a session variable. The only session variables exist within the `$_SESSION` array.